# check if list contains other string apart from 'apples' and 'oranges'

Tags: python, list

How to know if a list in python contains other elements apart from `'apples'` and `'oranges'`.

```
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges']
```

Now if the list fruits contains any other string suppose:

`fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', grapes']` 
or 
`fruits = ['oranges', grapes']`

How do I check?

Comment: Please tell what is your desired output. like 1) you want output list 2) only bool result or any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']

for i in fruits:
    if i not in ['apples','oranges']:
       print i  # Mismatched values will be printed
```

Output:

```
grapes
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [set object](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
target = ['apples', 'oranges']
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'whatever']

set(fruits) - set(target)
#=> {'whatever', 'grapes'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']
any(x not in ['apples', 'oranges'] for x in f)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want another list where items are apart from `'apples'` or `'oranges'`, try this :

```
fruits = [i for i in fruits if i not in ['apples', 'oranges']]
```

Comment: You should make a list of mismatches

`>>> fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'bananas']
>>> a_fruits = ['apples', 'oranges']
>>> [i for i in fruits if (i not in a_fruits)]
['grapes', 'bananas']`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `filter` list:

```
fruits_list = ['apples', 'oranges', 'mangoes']
filter_list =  ['apples', 'oranges']

print([x for x in fruits_list if x not in filter_list])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['mangoes']
```

Answer (score 0):

What behavior do you expect if there is several 'oranges' in your list?
I consider to ignore all doubling elements.

The function should stop the check once it finds any element other from checking list.

```
def check_if_there_something_else(original_list: list, checking_for: list):
    for fruit in original_list:
        if fruit not in checking_for:
            return True
    return False

original_list = ['oranges', 'oranges', 'grapes']
checking_for = ['oranges', 'grapes']
print(check_if_there_something_else(original_list, checking_for))
```

False

```
original_list = ['oranges', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'grapes', 'grapes', 'kiwi']
checking_for = ['oranges', 'grapes']
print(check_if_there_something_else(original_list, checking_for))
```

True

You can make almost the same check by finding difference between sets, but creating two new objects looks redundant:

```
print(any(set(original_list).difference(checking_for)))
```

True